# Reading RSS feeds --> not consistent

Tags: .net

i am trying to read the RSS feed by loading it to xmldocument

some thing like

```
xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(url);

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlTextReader);
```

some times the loading to xml document succeeds and some times it fails .

the url i am using is

http://rss.nzherald.co.nz/rss/xml/nzhrsscid_000000004.xml

what could be the probelm, is it like the RSS is not updated properly..?

any suggestions/comments

Regards
DEE

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 3.5, I would look into the System.ServiceModel.Syndication namespace. It provides a very rich and feed-format agnostic library for handling feeds in .NET. It also provides a lot of extensibility that allows you to plug in additional feed formatters, if needed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx

It should simplify your use of RSS, and help you track down odd problems like this, as it provides a cleaner abstraction.

Comment: thanks for the response,i am on 2.0 . the question is why RSS xml is not proper all the time ,and how to deal with it. does anyone have this problem or is it only me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SyndicationFeed clas. Here is a simple example which will show you clearly how to get this done. If the feed doesn't load then then feed is not constructed properly.

http://www.avantprime.com/articles/view-article/10/getting-syndication-feeds-(rss-atom)-in-.net